# How to print a usable stack trace in Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, stack-trace

I'm using `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` to log a stack trace when my app encounters an `NSError`, to help me troubleshoot and debug behavior my users see. It produces output like this:

```
(
    0   MyApp                               0x00000001067b02fc MyApp + 451324
    1   AppKit                              0x00007fff89e922c2 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 354
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff89e91e05 -[NSApplication run] + 231
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff89e14520 NSApplicationMain + 1176
    4   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff9bae25ad start + 1
)
```

How do I print in that same log statement the address into which `MyApp` has been loaded, so I can manually symbolicate the stack frame (in this case, finding out what method resides at `451324`)?

When looking at a crash report, for example, there is a section labeled "Binary Images" that lists the address of each binary. I'm looking for a way to get that for my own process, at runtime.

I found [this Apple documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/ControllingAppResponse.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000473-DontLinkElementID_3), which shows how to symbolicate by shelling out to `atos`, but I'd prefer a Cocoa API call.